# Suppressing "Bad system call" Message

Tags: c, linux, seccomp

As described [here](http://outflux.net/teach-seccomp/) ,using seccomp filters, we can block specific system calls when running example.c file.

The process will terminate and a "Bad system call" message will be printed:

```
$ ./example
Bad system call
```

I want to suppress the message.

Even this did not help:

```
$ ./example >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
Bad system call
```

Comment: Try `./example &> /dev/null`

Comment: @DavidRF Didn't work. Same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step is to understand where the `Bad system call` message comes from. It is a feature of your shell to tell you what signal caused your process to die. This message is not printed by your process, but by your shell. When the shell executes a program, it waits for it to finish using the `waitpid` system call. In the `status` parameter the reason for termination is described and the shell evaluates that field and kindly prints a message. Similarly when you manually kill a process launched from a shell with the `SIGKILL` signal, that shell will print `Killed`.

Now you already figured how to get rid of the message. You need to redirect the output of the shell by starting a subshell and redirecting its output.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to ignore something, that you are not supposed to ignore. "Bad system call" seems a serious failure.

But, if you HAVE TO ignore it, try:

```
(./example) >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

I have not tested this, but I have seen this working, when simple `>/dev/null 2>&1` don't work.

e.g. with `(some-command) >/dev/null 2>/dev/null`, if you `kill -9` this some-command, the `killed` message printed on screen is not printed.

Comment: Didn't work. I needed to do this because everything printed by my bash script is used by another script and I wanted to suppress this message. Now I think it is better to print only desired messages to a file and use that file in second script.

Comment: If that message "Bad system call" is not present on stdout, then I hardly think, that this will be logged using any method & thus will be passed to that another script. Unless, you are doing some operations using screen or similar command.

Comment: I put the command in my script `tester.sh`. Now when I run `./tester.sh 2>/dev/null`, that message doesn't appear.